# Parsing the Data in java

Tags: java, c

I am using

```
i=sscanf(input,"%f %c %f",&operand1,operator,&operand2);
```

in C for parsing the input which  is of the format

```
operand1   operator  operand2
```

operator can be `+ - * / ^`
operand `+` or `-` any double

is there any method similar in JAVA

Comment: You can get the input and then use regex to find and match patterns in java.

Comment: What about `Scanner#nextXXX`?

Comment: Does [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70618619/17850902) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a convenient option is to use the `java.util.Scanner`-class.
The following code snippet should get you going to parse inputs:

```java
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class ScannerExample {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      // Declare variables
      Scanner s;
      float f1;
      float f2;
      char op;
      
      // Ask for input data
      System.out.println("Enter Data: ");

      // Initialize a Scanner-object using stdin
      s = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      // Read and parse the data
      f1 = s.nextFloat();
      op = s.next().charAt(0);
      f2 = s.nextFloat();
      
      System.out.println(f1 + " " + op + " " + f1);

      // Closes the scanner
      s.close();
    }
}
```

Error checking was omitted for the sake of brevity.

*Edit:*
As @electricchef pointed out, one could also use the [`useDelimiter(Pattern pattern)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.util.regex.Pattern))-function of `Scanner` as an alternative approach, like so:

```java
s = new Scanner(System.in);
s.useDelimiter("\\s+");
f1 = s.nextFloat();
op = s.next().charAt(0);
f2 = s.nextFloat();
```

Here, the input is splitted at one or more whitespace-characters as it is denoted by the regex-pattern `"\\s+"`.

Comment: You could also use the use set delimiter function of Scanner to select operators etc.

Comment: Good point, I added it as an alternative solution, @electricchef